# How to handle onClick() in 100 buttons?

Tags: java, android, refactoring

I have 100 buttons in layout and `OnClick()` method for all of it.

If I use `switch` I need to do `case R.id.button1, ..., case R.id.button100` for all 100 buttons. How to shorten this code?

```
public void webClick(View v) 
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button1:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Webview.class);
        intent.putExtra("weblink","file:///android_asset/chapter/chapter1.html");
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    case R.id.button2:
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Webview.class);
        intent2.putExtra("weblink","file:///android_asset/chapter/chapter2.html");
        startActivity(intent2);
        break;

    // ...

    case R.id.button100:
        Intent intent100 = new Intent(this, Webview.class);
        intent100.putExtra("weblink","file:///android_asset/chapter/chapter100.html");
        startActivity(intent100);
        break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Use an index to select button array element, to alter string(chapter[x]) and to select intent array. Or make a class that has each one of these and create array of the class.

Comment: Why you need 100 Buttons for selecting a chapter?

Comment: @pad i have 100 chapters, so i need 100 buttons

Comment: Why no textfield with one button to change the chapter?

Comment: One word - `Listview`.  A hundred buttons is a usability nightmare.

Answer (score 5):

If the URL depends directly on the ID, then try this:

```
public void webClick(View v) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Webview.class);
    intent.putExtra("weblink","file:///android_asset/chapter/chapter" + v.getId() + ".html");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

EDITED

In the case you URL doesn't depend directly on the ID, then try mapping button IDs with URLS, like this:

```
Map<Integer, String> urls = new HashMap();

urls.put(R.id.button1, "file:///android_asset/chapter/chapter100.html");
// ... 1 to 100 ...
```

and modify the above code like this:

```
public void webClick(View v) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Webview.class);
    intent.putExtra("weblink", urls.get(v.getId()));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

EDITED #2

If in the label of your buttons you already have the URL, a sugestion (not mine but made by @pad) would be to use it to calculate the URL this way:

```
public void webClick(View v) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Webview.class);
    intent.putExtra("weblink", "file:///android_asset/chapter/chapter" + v.getText().replaceAll("Chapter ","") + ".html"); // Assuming your text is like "Chapter 50"
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: May need to do a replace around the Id to strip "button"

Comment: The id is auto generated and thus can not be predictable

Comment: Maybe you can use a Integer from the buttonname, but the id won't work as good. `button1.getText()`

Comment: @morgano: if i used this, it navigates to file:///android_asset/chapter/chapter2131230722.html

Comment: @user2648429 answer improved.

Comment: do i have to copy these for 100 times ? `urls.put(R.id.button1, "file:///android_asset/chapter/chapter100.html");`

Comment: Yes for each Chapter. How are thes buttons name `getText()`?

Comment: That's practically the same amount of copy-pastes (e.g. filling the urls map). The problem here is how to shorten the code as much as possible.

Comment: 100 mappings are still less code than 100 switch cases with almost the same code between them

Comment: Sure but in an other thread he showed that the buttons are named like "Chapter X" so you can change your answer. Insted of `v.getID()` just use `v.getText().replaceAll(' ','')`.

Comment: @morgano - well technically yes, but the switches also can be shoretened and the only different part of the will be `intent.putExtra("weblink","file:///android_asset/chapter/chapter%.html");`, the other parts can be put outside of all the `switches`. So I don't really see how much code is spared with this.

Comment: @pad I added your suggestion, but why didn't you answer directly the question?

Comment: I have allready asked him above and answered him in an other thread. Here you can see the XML Mapping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056935/id-is-not-mapping-with-the-value

Answer (score 2):

For more number of buttons in your case, Dynamically create button in a loop and assign onclick event like..

Create one `LinearLayout` in your xml file.

Now add this all buttons in that LinearLayout like..

```
String[] urls={url1,url2.....url100}; //  here write your all URLs
Button button[]= new Button[100];
LinearLayout mainlinear=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layer);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            button[i] = new Button(this);
            button[i].setText(i);
            button[i].setTag(i+":"+URL); // URL = What you need to pass when button is click
            button[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    TextView selected = (TextView) v;
                                    String tag = selected.getTag().toString();

            //Here you need to write your code when button is pressed.

Intent intent = new Intent(this, Webview.class);
        intent2.putExtra("weblink",urls[i]);
        startActivity(intent2);
            }

            }
    mainlinear.addView(button[i]);
```

Comment: i am very new to android and java. can u please tel me what should i do in detail ? because i like this approach

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should be working:

```
public void webClick(View v) 
            {
                  String stringID = String.valueOf(v.getId());
                  String[] temp = stringID.split("utton");
                  stringID = "file:///android_asset/chapter/chapter" +temp[1]+ ".html"
                  Intent intent = new Intent(this, Webview.class);
                  intent.putExtra("weblink",stringID);
                  startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Comment: You can add an if statement, to see if temp[1] is containing a numer (it's a string in here alright) between the number of buttons you have.

Comment: If the function name `webClick` is in the layouts of all the buttons in `android:onClick="webClick"`, then I don't see a reason why it shouldn't.

Comment: Error : opening trace file, no such file or directory. but i have files in the directory. path is correct

Comment: I modified the answer, try it like that. This can be due to the fact, that I'm concatenating the address inside the `putExtra()` method. I put this ouside of the method, append it to a String variable and then pass this variable to the method as a second argument. Try to output the address in a LOG to see if there's something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a ListView. If you want to have buttons, then use a ListView, which has one button in each item's layout.

Then, you setup a onItemClickListener. You get the position of that button (the first one has position 0, the second has position 1, etc.). Then compose a link:

```
String link= "file:///android_asset/chapter/chapter" + (position +1) + ".html";
```

The rest of your code, would be the same (`intent.putExtra("weblink", link);`)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a ListView or GridView for this case and save the file names in an ArrayList. Then you do something like this:

```
List<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();
urlList.add("file:///android_asset/chapter/chapter1.html");
urlList.add("file:///android_asset/chapter/chapter2.html");
// and so on

ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.id.simple_list_item_1, urlList);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Webview.class);
                    intent.putExtra("weblink", urlList.get(position));
                    startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

This would be a nice implementation because you would avoid using 100 Buttons and OnClickListeners to save some ressources.

Edit: This code should be running, just put it in onCreate() for some testing. All you have to do is to define a ListView in your layout.xml insteed of the 100 buttons like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
  android:orientation="vertical"  
  android:layout_width="match_parent"  
  android:layout_height="match_parent">  

    <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"   
      android:layout_height="match_parent"   
      android:id="@+id/listView">  
    </ListView>  

</LinearLayout>
```

If you really wanna use this with Buttons than follow morgano's suggestion.

Comment: @steve_benett: i am very new t android and java. can u please tel me what should i do in detail ?

Answer (score -5):

```
public void webClick(View v) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Webview.class);

    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button1:
            intent.putExtra("weblink","file:///android_asset/chapter/chapter1.html");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            intent.putExtra("weblink","file:///android_asset/chapter/chapter2.html");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case R.id.button3:
            intent.putExtra("weblink","file:///android_asset/chapter/chapter3.html");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
.
.
.
.

        case R.id.button100:
            intent.putExtra("weblink","file:///android_asset/chapter/chapter100.html");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
     }

}
```